# Dropdown list in PowerBuilder can't retrieve all data

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have created in powerbuilder a dropdown data window to function as a filter to get values from a table named product and then by selecting something from the dropdown list in another datawindow to show all the retrieved data associated with the selection from the dropdown list.

Its working fine, the code in my `w_firstwindow` in `open()` is like that

```
datawindowchild child_data
dw_prod_filter.insertrow(0)
if dw_prod_filter.getchild( 'productname', child_data ) = 1 then
  child_data.settransobject( SQLCA )
  child_data.retrieve( )    
  child_data.insertrow(1)
  child_data.setitem( 1, 'name', 'ALL' )
  child_data.setitem( 1, 'picture_name', 'ALL' )
  child_data.selectrow( 0, false )  
end if
```

in the datawindow filter `dw_prod_filter` in the `itemchanged()` I have this

```
string ls_product

ls_product = dw_prod_filter.GetItemString(row,'productname')

dw_product_list.retrieve( data )
```

and in the `dw_product_list` in the `constructor()` I have this

```
 this.setTransObject( SQLCA )
```

I have made and the necessary retrieval arguments through power builder and is working fine.

BUT,

I want when I select the ALL option from the dropdown list to retrieve the whole table product, I have tried many things with no luck,, and I was wondering if anyone can help me out, any help would be really appreciated,

Thank you in advance guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the SQL statement for dw_product_list look like - specifically the WHERE clause?

-Paul-

Comment: SELECT "product"."id",   
         "product"."name",   
         "product"."description",   
         "product"."prod_size",   
         "product"."color",   
         "product"."quantity",   
         "product"."unit_price",   
         "product"."picture_name"  
    FROM "product"  
   WHERE ( "product"."name" = :name OR  
         :name is null )

Comment: Well, you're setting the value of the dropdown for "ALL" to the string "ALL", so change the WHERE clause to:

WHERE ( "product"."name" = :name OR :name = 'ALL' )

Comment: NoazDad thank you so much for the info it worked like a charm by adding as well in the dddw dw_prod_filter the following script,

Comment: string ls_product
setnull(ls_product)

if dw_prod_filter.GetItemString(1,'productname') = 'ALL' then dw_product_list.retrieve( 'ALL' )

ls_product = dw_prod_filter.GetItemString(row,'productname')
dw_product_list.retrieve( data )

Answer (score 0):

Example:

In itemchanged()

```
string ls_product
ls_product = dw_prod_filter.GetItemString(row,'productname')
dw_product_list.retrieve( ls_product )
```

In SELECT:

```
SELECT "product"."id", "product"."name", "product"."description", "product"."prod_size", "product"."color", "product"."quantity", "product"."unit_price", "product"."picture_name" FROM "product" WHERE ( "product"."name" = :name OR "product"."name" is null )
```